# solaris smc how to authenticate root?

Tags: solaris

I have enabled smc:

```
svcadm enable svc:/application/management/wbem:default
```

run smc as root,ok

Select info, or patches or whatever, and it asks for the root password.

I put in the correct password but it is still asking for the root password. 
I have missed something?

Comment: The SMC [troubleshooting](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26505_01/html/E29492/smcover-119.html#smcover-84) documentation doesn't go very far ("is it running? start it or restart it."); you may need to open an SR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With SMC, I think you need to login to the webadmin interface with a browser.  In order to use it, memory is that you needed to assign privs and roles in RBAC.

You mention patches, so perhaps you want `smpatch`?